# JSF bidirectional set managed bean property value as another bean property

Tags: jsf, managed-bean, faces-config

I'm trying to set a managed property value from another bean.

faces-config.xml

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>beanA</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.project.BeanA</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>view</managed-bean-scope>

    <managed-property>
        <property-name>value</property-name>
        <value>#{sessionBean.currentValue}</value>
    </managed-property>
</managed-bean>

<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>sessionBean</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>com.project.SessionBean</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

`SessionBean.java` and `BeanA.java`

```
class SessionBean {
    private Object currentValue; // getter+setter
}
class BeanA {
    private Object value; // getter+setter
}
```

I understand that the value standing in `sessionBean.currentValue` gets dumped into `beanA.value`, but when setting any value (from `beanA`) like `beanA.setValue(x)`, `sessionBean.currentValue` remains unaltered - is this expected? If so how to enable this bidirectionality?